# Store latitude and longitude in database Android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I am working on android app for my school project. My app is tracking time and distance while I am running and after that I am showing the track on the google map. I want to store every single run into SQLite database and my question is what is the effective way to store lat and long into database?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: No I haven't. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Well, the *obvious* way is to use columns named `lon` and `lat`. Why do you have doubts?

Answer (score 0):

for getting latlon, use this one :

```
 String lat = Double.toStirng(location.getLatitude());
 String lon = Double.toStirng(location.getLongtitude());
```

then store it on your db.

ps, i dont know your database implementation so that i cannot configure the db.. which means you have to know that one:)

Comment: hi guys i want to show a location on google map and then save its coordinates(lat lon) into sqlite database, please guide me